Displaying child pages and file URL in an ACF relationship field shortcode
Just to outline my scenario; I have some basic pages and a CPT called 'Resources'. The 'Resources' post type has an ACF file field called 'pdf_file' The pages have an ACF relationship field which enables Resources to be linked to each page. These pages will then be rendered on the front end as a simple list with links to their respective PDF file.
The Resources post type is setup in a parent/child structure.
I have something in place I have recycled from another project, which cycles through the related posts and outputs the title and URL. I'm trying to modify this in order to output not only the PDF file link but also the parent child structure.
So an example would be
'Page 1' has 'Resource 1' as a related post
'Resource 1' has 2 child posts; 'Resource 2' and 'Resource 3'
So on the frontend of 'Page 1', the rendered list would read as
Resource 1 (with PDF link)
Resource 2 (with PDF link)
Resource 3 (with PDF link)
The code I currently have is below
add_shortcode( 'ca_acf_relationship_field', 'ca_get_relationship_field' ); 

function ca_get_relationship_field( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    
    global $post;
    $defaults = array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID, // Default to the current Post ID.
        'field'   => 'related_resource',
    );
    
    $args = wp_parse_args( $atts, $defaults );
    
    $related_posts = get_field( $args['field'], $args['post_id'] );

    // Check if we have a single post (post object, post ID) or an
    // array of posts then convert to array.
    if( is_object( $related_posts ) ) {
        $related_posts = array( $related_posts );
    } else if ( is_scalar( $related_posts ) ) {
        $related_posts = array( $related_posts );
    }
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        ?>
        
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $related_posts as $related_post ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $related_post ) ) {
                $related_post = get_post( $related_post );
            }
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $related_post->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title( $related_post->ID ) ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me in displaying the child posts and also being able to render the PDF file URL in the link. This is something I've never really been able to accomplish
Thanks
